# Creating texture with varying alpha values for drawing anti-aliased lines in OpenGL-ES

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, textures, alpha

I am working on drawing anti-aliased lines in OpenGL-ES on iPhone. I am using an approach outlined in *iPhone 3D Programming*, called "Rendering Anti-Aliased Lines with Textures". The basis idea is to iterate through the line creating a bounding rectangle for each line segment (pair of vertices). This bounding rectangle can be represented by 6 triangles - and these can be filled with a texture. A texture (dot.png) comes with sample code, but I would like to experiment with other textures to see if I can get a more 3 dimensional affect.

So, I am wondering if there is a tool that would help me create these texture images. I have tried using Photoshop - but my skills there are rudimentary. I have seen "GIMP" mentioned, but I have no experience with it. I am guessing/hoping that there is some app out there that is designed for this purpose. Any pointers would be most welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean, to create some blurry circles you can try to generate some using imagemagick. Some examples are here for blurring www.imagemagick.org/Usage/blur/
and here for radial gradients: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/canvas/#radial-gradient and www.imagemagick.org/script/fx.php

Comment: Thanks, Pablo.

I found another way (in Photoshop) as well - which I had meant to post already.

Here is what you can do.
- Create a document the size you need.

- Use the Elliptical marquee tool while holding shift to make a perfect circle selection.

- Select the gradient tool.

- Open the gradient picker.

- There are a series of stored gradients to select in the picker including ones that have an alpha value gradient.

- Select radial gradient.

- find the center of you selection, and drag the gradient tool from the middle to the edge of the selection.